# Match eraser settings to brush settings

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm painting with a brush in Photoshop, and I want to use the same brush as the eraser. What's the quickest way to get identical settings for the brush and the eraser tool?

Comment: Theoretically you could make a script that saves the brush preset and switches to either brush tool or eraser tool depending on which one was selected and then selects the brush preset that was created last.

Comment: A Mask using the brush would be the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs a way to quickly change your current brush into an eraser in photoshop, try this:

1. First, get and install autohotkey. It's a simple hotkey automation scripting language for windows:  https://www.autohotkey.com/
2. Open Notepad
3. Copy and Paste the following code into notepad:

```
#IfWinActive,ahk_exe Photoshop.exe
normal={N}
clear={R}

e::
erase:= !erase ? 1 : 0
keys:= !erase ? normal : clear
Send,{Shift Down}{Alt Down}
Send,% keys
Send,{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
return
```

4. Save this script somewhere on your computer.
   Change the "save as filetype"  to  "All Files" instead of txt.
   Save your script under an easy name like "Photoshop Eraser Brush.ahk".
   It can be any name as long as you use the .ahk extension.
5. Now go to where you saved your script and double click it to run.
6. Back in Photoshop, try pressing the "E" key to switch back and forth between the eraser and normal mode.
7. To quit the script, just look for the little green and white "A" icon in your system tray, right-click, and exit.

If you'd like to change the "E" key to something else, just change the part of your script with "e::" to another key. Autohotkey also comes with a good help file full of examples.  This script works in cs6 - cc 2019 in my testing so far.
Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

The all-new Photoshop 2020 has this feature.

While you're using the brush, hold the  <kbd>~</kbd>  and the brush now is an eraser keeping the settings of the brush.

But, if you'll not switch to the new version, there is a solution:

You can change de brush mode from Normal (or whatever) to Clear.

Edit: Using shortcuts to change the mode:  <kbd>Shit</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd>  = Clear Mode.  <kbd>Shit</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>N</kbd>  = Normal Mode.